# Parsing multiple line records using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, sql, parsing, csv, stream

There was a suggestion in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469304/parsing-multi-line-records-using-java-8-streams) to move this question here. I added some more information and restructured the question a bit.

I'm trying to parse the following file which contains information in the following format:

> TABLE_NAME
>
> VARIABLE_LIST_OF_COLUMNS
>
> VARIABLE_NUMBER_OF_ROWS (Seperated by a tab seperator)

An example (using ',' as the seperator for the question; actual seperator is a tab):

> STUDENTS
>
> ID
>
> NAME
>
> 1,Mike
>
> 2,Kimberly

The idea is to build a list of insert sql statements (context for the code snippet). So the output would be (ignore numeric/null values for now):

> INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID, NAME) VALUES ('1','Mike');
>
> INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID, NAME) VALUES ('2','Kimberly');

What I want to know is whether this kind of multiline parsing is at all possible using java 8 streams API? This is what I have at the moment:

```
public final class StatementGeneratorMain {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{
        List<String> fileNames = Arrays
            .asList("STUDENTS.txt");
        fileNames.stream()
            .forEach(fileName -> {
                String tableName;
                List<String> columnNames;
                List<String[]>  dataRows;
                try (BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(fileName)) {
                    tableName = br.lines().findFirst().get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                try (BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(fileName)) {
                    //skip the first line because its been processed.
                    columnNames = br.lines().skip(1).filter(v -> v.split("\t").length == 1).collect(toList());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                try (BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(fileName)) {
                    //skip the first line and the columns length to get the data
                    //columns are identified as being splittable on the delimiter
                    dataRows = br.lines().skip(1 + columnNames.size()).map(s -> s.split("\t"))
                        .collect(toList());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                String columns = columnNames.stream().collect(joining(",","(",")"));

                List<String> dataRow = dataRows.stream()
                    .map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(x -> "'" + x + "'").collect(joining(",", "(", ")")))
                    .map(row -> String.format("INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s;", tableName, columns, row))
                    .collect(toList());

                dataRow.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l));
            });
    }

    private static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(String fileName) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(StatementGeneratorMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            fileName)));
    }
}
```

This piece of code does the job for me, but I don't really like it because I read the same file thrice (once for table name, again to deduce the columns, again to get the rows). I also don't think that it is proper functional style.

**What I am looking for is a more elegant way to do this kind of multiline/multirecord parsing using the streams API.**

What I thought about:

- Using `Files.lines()` instead of `BufferedReader`.
- Using `partitioningBy()` instead of `filter().collect(toList())` when parsing the columns, then true values goes into the column list and false values goes into the dataRows list.

I'm not too particular about stuff like numeric column and null values at this point.

Comment: 1. You're opening the same file too many times. 2. Is it possible to re-jig your file contents so that they adhere to a more common schema-validated type, such as XML or JSON? See [this on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/284707/119814) to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: @h.j.k 1. That's sort of the main problem that caused me to post the question :) 2. Unfortunately not

Comment: ok, assuming if you can turn your file into a XML file, you can use any reliable third-party XML marshaling library to do all these content parsing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you only need a `Consumer<String>`-implementing class that knows what lines to read as the table name, the columns and rows.

```
public class StatementGenerator implements Consumer<String> {

    private static String START = " (";
    private static String END = ") ";
    private static String ROW_DELIMITER = "\n";

    private String delimiter = "\t";
    private String parameter = "%";
    private ObjIntConsumer<List<String>> parameterSupplier =
            (list, i) -> { list.add(parameter); };
    private String table = null;
    private List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    public void setParameterSupplier(ObjIntConsumer<List<String>> parameterSupplier) {
        this.parameterSupplier = parameterSupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String t) {
        if (table == null) {
            table = t;
            return;
        }
        if (!t.contains(delimiter)) {
            columns.add(t);
            return;
        }
        rows.add(t);
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return table;
    }

    public List<String> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public List<String> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public String getParameterizedStatement() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO ");
        result.append(constructSegment(getTableName(), getColumns())).append(
                constructSegment("VALUES", IntStream.rangeClosed(1, getColumns().size())
                        .collect(ArrayList::new, parameterSupplier, List::addAll)));
        return result.append(";").toString();
    }

    public List<String> getRawStatements() {
        String placeholderStatement = getParameterizedStatement()
                .replaceAll(Pattern.quote(parameter), "%s");
        return getRows().stream().map(r -> String.format(placeholderStatement,
                    Pattern.compile(delimiter).splitAsStream(r)
                        .map(v -> "'" + v + "'").toArray()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getFullStatement() {
        return getRawStatements().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(ROW_DELIMITER));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getParameterizedStatement();
    }

    private static String constructSegment(String prefix, List<String> list) {
        return prefix + list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ", START, END));
    }
}
```

In my sample implementation above, I've made the `delimiter` configurable, but there's one other configuration I want to highlight - `parameter`.

### SQL injection

The sample implementation provides a `getParameterizedStatement()` as the starting point, because by right you should let your database driver handle the escaping of quotes (and possibly other magic values). We certainly do not need [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) to hang around here.

The parameter list is driven by an `ObjIntConsumer`, because if I'm not mistaken, there are certain drivers allowing for an index-based parameter substitution. That will mean you can potentially override `parameterSupplier` with something like `(list, i) -> { list.add("::" + i); };` (or whatever the placeholder format is).

With that said, assuming you can ***absolutely trust your file-based input*** (i.e. sanitized inputs), we can then proceed with using `getRawStatements()`, which performs a simple substitution on the `parameter` with our `String.format()`'s `"%s"` placeholder. This is more aligned with what you are asking for. `getFullStatement()` simply concatenates all the rows into a single `String`, if that is what you actually require.

Here's what I used in my `main()` code:

```
public class StatementGeneratorMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        StatementGenerator generator = new StatementGenerator();
        generator.setDelimiter(",");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(
                ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sqlRecords.txt").toURI()))) {
            lines.forEach(generator);
        }
        System.out.println(generator.getTableName());
        System.out.println(generator.getColumns());
        System.out.println(generator.getParameterizedStatement());
        generator.getRawStatements().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And the sample output:

```
STUDENTS
[ID, NAME]
INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID, NAME) VALUES (%, %) ;
INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID, NAME) VALUES ('1', 'Mike') ;
INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID, NAME) VALUES ('2', 'Kimberly') ;
```

Comment: I really like the way the `accept()` method was implemented. I would +10 if I could since it changed my way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a long lambda.  It deserves to be a method of its own.

There is a fundamental limit to how much can be done using functional programming, since the very act of reading from the `BufferedReader` alters its state.  [In Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_IO), for example, all I/O is a bit of a hassle, using the `IO` monad to indicate that the function has side-effects of consuming input or producing output.

A further complication here is that the first few lines are to be treated differently.  Moreover, the result from the first few lines is to be used in the rest of the response.  Making a `Stream` consisting of all lines of the file is therefore not a great idea.

For those reasons, I recommend abandoning the idea of using streams for processing the header.  Here's my suggestion:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StatementGeneratorMain {
    private static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader cl = StatementGeneratorMain.class.getClassLoader();
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cl.getResourceAsStream(fileName)));
    }

    private static Stream<String> toSql(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String tableName = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            br.mark(256);  // max length of column name or first data column
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line.indexOf("\t") >= 0) {
                // End of header; this is a row of data
                br.reset();
                break;
            }
            columnNames.add(line);
        } while (true);
        String columns = columnNames.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        return br.lines()
                 .map(row -> row.replace("'", "''").replace("\t", "', '"))
                 .map(row -> String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES('%s');",
                                           tableName, columns, row));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader("STUDENTS.txt")) {
            toSql(br).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this approach is vulnerable to SQL injection.  I've done some rudimentary escaping using `row.replace("'", "''")`, but that might not protect you against all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little offtopic but...

I've had almost the same task not so long ago. The task was to parse CSV file and insert data into specified table. To deal with it I've used `org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.1` library. Its capable of parsing csv files into column name to column value map.

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream('');
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is)) {
   CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(reader) //Excel is for tab separated files, use DEFAULT format for CSV
   for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
       result.add(record.toMap());
   }
}
```

That will give you a list of maps from CSV file that you can pass to bulk insert query builder method (or lambda if you want to).

Sample file format:

```
ID,NAME
1,Mike
2,Kimberly
```

Comment: The header format being handled here is a bit weirder, though. Each column name is on its own line.

Comment: @200_success I'm not telling that my solution will work for stated file format but if OP is in power to change the format there's a good library for this task